# Getting Large Twitter User Lists (And Retrying)

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm trying to get the list of follower user IDs for a certain handle. Something like

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(...)
client.follower_ids(handle).each { |id| puts id }
```

But for a handle with thousands of followers I get `Twitter::Error:TooManyRequests`. I considered trying

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(...)
begin
  client.follower_ids(handle).each { |id| puts id }
rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
  sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in
  retry
end
```

But won't that restart the `each` loop from the beginning every time I get `TooManyRequests` (and thus never finish)?

I am using the twitter gem v5.8.0.

Comment: Yep, if a given user has over 75K followers (15 * 5K), then I don't think there is a way to fetch all the IDs. Same goes for friends IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem repo was recently updated with an [example](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/RateLimiting.md) of how to do this properly.

The key is to put *only* the loop inside the block.

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(...)
follower_ids = client.follower_ids(handle)
begin
  follower_ids.each { |id| puts id }
rescue Twitter::Error::TooManyRequests => error
  sleep error.rate_limit.reset_in
  retry
end
```

---

#### Warning:

My example is no good!

This code works because the cursor caches the results of each request, so that each time it retries, it doesn't need to request everything from the start. However it *does* loop through everything already cached before making another request.

This code will output IDs multiple times, whenever a retry occurs. If you write code like this, you need to include something that prevents duplication of loop iterations.